# Drupal "Most recent nodes" in menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-navigation

Is there any way to add the 5 most recent nodes of a certain type to the primary links menu? I am using the nicemenus module and basically want to add a main menu link that says "Stories" with a dropdown menu that shows the five most recent stories.

Is this possible? I have no problems creating a view that shows me what I want, but I dont know how to get it to the menu.

Thanks!
/Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply turn views results into menu items, because menu items are cached while views are dynamic. There is a module that tries to bridge that gap: [Views build menu](http://drupal.org/project/views_build_menu). Basically it runs your view with a certain interval and rebuilds the menu items. I haven't tried it myself and it's still in alpha. If you decide to give it a try, please let us know if it worked for you.

Comment: Seems like a very good solution! There are still some issues i'm trying to work out, but for the most part everything works well! Thanks